# Angular : How can I get parent component with child routes to react to URL changes (which include child route param changes)?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

This is my current route setup. (Note: ScheduleComponent is loaded by the main app when we want to see the Schedule screen)
ScheduleComponent has a `<route-outlet>` for the child routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ScheduleComponent,
    data: {
      screenName: 'schedule',
    },
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'ABC', pathMatch: 'full' },
      {
        path: ':service',
        component: ScheduleTilesContainerComponent,
        data: {
          screenName: 'schedule',
        },
      },
      {
        path: ':service/:year/:month/:day',
        component: ScheduleTilesContainerComponent,
        data: {
          screenName: 'schedule',
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

In ScheduleComponent I have:

```
// this._route: ActivatedRoute (in constructor)
this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
 console.log('Schedule params: ', params);
}
```

In ScheduleTilesContainerComponent I have:

```
// this._route: ActivatedRoute (in constructor)
this._route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
 console.log('Tiles Container params: ', params);
}
```

---

### **SCENARIO A:**

When we put this in the browser: `http://myserver.com/schedule`
We see this in the console:

```
Schedule params: {}
Schedule params: {service: "ABC"}
TileContainer params: {service: "ABC"}
```

Then a user interaction triggers this:
`this._router.navigate(['schedule/ABC/2020/03/25']);`

Then we see in the browser address bar: `http://myserver.com/schedule/ABC/2020/03/25`
We see this in the console:

```
TileContainer params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "25"}
```

Then a user interaction triggers this:
`this._router.navigate(['schedule/ABC/2020/03/11']);`
Then we see in the browser address bar: `http://myserver.com/schedule/ABC/2020/03/11`
We see this in the console:

```
TileContainer params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "11"}
```

**Question 1:  How come the ScheduleComponent is not seeing the params observable stream trigger when we navigate()?**

Continuing...
Then I click the BACK button:
We see in the browser address bar: `http://myserver.com/schedule/ABC/2020/03/25` (correct previous URL)
We see this in the console:

```
TileContainer params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "25"}
```

**Question 2:  How come the ScheduleComponent is not seeing the params observable stream trigger here as well? (it's probably the same issue)**

---

### **SCENARIO B**

HOWEVER, if THIS is the way we enter the screen, then the ScheduleComponent DOES get the param stream!

Put this into the browser directly: `http://myserver.com/schedule/ABC/2020/03/25`

```
Schedule params: {}
Schedule params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "25"}
TileContainer params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "25"}
```

Then a user interaction triggers this:
`this._router.navigate(['schedule/ABC/2020/03/11']);`

```
Schedule params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "11"}
TileContainer params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "11"}
```

If we click the BACK button the prev URL shows...
We this this in the console:

```
Schedule params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "25"}
TileContainer params: {service: "ABC", year: "2020, month: "03", day: "25"}
```

**Question 3: Why does the ScheduleComponent's param stream see this change?**

**Question 4: How can I get my ScheduleComponent to ALWAYS see the URL update?**